# Ordinal logistic regression in Python

Tags: categorical-data, python, logit, ordered-logit, statsmodels

I would like to run an ordinal logistic regression in Python - for a response variable with three levels and with a few explanatory factors. The `statsmodels` package supports binary logit and multinomial logit (MNLogit) models, but not ordered logit. Since the underlying math is not that different, I wonder if it can be implemented easily using these?  (Alternatively, other Python packages that work are appreciated.)

Comment: The only code in python that I know of is by Fabian see the statsmodels issue https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/807 . I think it wouldn't be difficult to implement for statsmodels, but nobody volunteered yet.

Comment: This is not Python, but in R the `orm` function in the `rms` package efficiently handles thousands of levels of the response variable.

Comment: In conjunction w/ @FrankHarrell's comment above, note that you can call R functions from Python w/ [rpy2](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-dev/html/introduction.html) (see also: [A Slug's Guide to Python](https://sites.google.com/site/aslugsguidetopython/data-analysis/pandas/calling-r-from-python)).

Comment: This is arguably on-topic since the question doesn't seem to be a pure code request - whether one can cobble an ordered logit model out of the computational ingredients of binary logit and MNLogit seems to me to be a question with a statistical character (even if the ultimate solution turns out to be something like "no, use a different package")

Comment: Indeed, I ended up using R modules through rpy2, as well as simplifying my model specification to binary logit.

Answer (score 14):

`statsmodels` now supports Ordinal Regression:

```
from statsmodels.miscmodels.ordinal_model import OrderedModel
```

[see their documentation here](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/examples/notebooks/generated/ordinal_regression.html)

Comment: statsmodels now supports Ordinal Regression, but not in the released version.  They say that installing the dev version of statsmodels is okay for everyday use. So I did:

`pip3 install git+git://github.com/someuser/someproject.git`

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried [Mord](http://pythonhosted.org/mord/)? It seems there are very few packages to do the same, and it is one of them; though, as Fabian himself suspects, code may not scale properly. [Source: Logistic ordinal regression in Python](http://fa.bianp.net/blog/2013/logistic-ordinal-regression/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want more flexibility to customize the distributional assumptions, you could do a Bayesian ordered logistic regression using PyMC. You would need to use the `pymc.OrderedLogistic` base class.

The documentation has the tutorial [*Regression Models with Ordered Categorical Outcomes*](https://www.pymc.io/projects/examples/en/latest/generalized_linear_models/GLM-ordinal-regression.html) which should provide a sructured guide for how to setup the code.